# How can you access Mozilla Thunderbird Emails (Read, Attachments, Filter By Subject, Etc.) using Python?

Tags: python, email-attachments, thunderbird

I just wondered what modules could be used? I've not **scraped** from Emails Before! So some advice/documentation would be great!

Comment: That depends entirely on how the email is stored. There are a bunch of ways that Thunderbird can be configured. For starters, are you using IMAP or POP3? If POP3, are you keeping messages on the server?

Comment: IMAP seems more practical for me

Comment: ...what does "sounds more realistic" mean? Do you have a concrete example in front of you? Does it use IMAP or not?

Comment: Whats the difference?

Comment: Between what? IMAP and POP3?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what the difference is?

Comment: There are lots of differences, but the most relevant here is probably that IMAP essentially syncs with your mail server, which means you don't need to do anything with Thunderbird at all; you can simply query the server using a protocol designed for exactly that, e.g. using [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html).

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks